# Android change app launcher icon without killing app

Tags: android

We are trying to change app icon. According to resources we use code as below.
if we run this code when app is runtime then it kill the app.
PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP does not work.
Is there way to change app icon without killig app ?

```
private fun creteComponentName(context: Context, aliasName: String): ComponentName {
    return ComponentName(context, pkg  + aliasName)
}

private fun enableIcon(
    context: Context,
    aliasName: String
){
    context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        creteComponentName(context, aliasName),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
}

private fun disableIcon(
    context: Context,
    aliasName: String
){
    context.packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        creteComponentName(context, aliasName),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
}
```

Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity-alias
        android:name="StageOneLauncherAlias"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name="StageSecondLauncherAlias"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that this will work without a reboot. It will depend on the launcher implementation and whether it detects this change.

Comment: Yeah, that's always been hacky and unreliable, but there's some relevant info in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68576022.